# How to make the cursor in the terminal to stop blinking after it loses focus?

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d, gnome-terminal, cursor

I noticed strange behavior in gnome-terminal: When the terminal has focus, the cursor is blinking. After it loses focus, the cursor keeps blinking for about 10 seconds, then stops. I'd like the cursor to stop blinking immediately after the focus is lost (and to start blinking immediately after the focus is gained). Is there a way to do that?

I'm on 12.04 with unity-2d and have the focus follows mouse policy enabled.

Comment: I think the cursor stops blinking immediately after the window looses focus whichever this setting is. I appears to me that this settings is for how long the cursor blinks if you don't do anything (as long as the window has the focus).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the command line run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-timeout 0
```

Comment: I had to use 1, as 0 is outside the valid range apparently, but it is good enough for me. Thanks man!

Comment: cursor-blink-timeout does not care if gnome-terminal has focus or not. Once the timeout is reached, the cursor does not blink, regardless of whether or not gnome-terminal has focus.